# Ambiguous overload - partial function template ordering with parameter packs

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

Consider the following contrived piece of code:

```
template <class... > struct pack { };

template <class R, class T, class... Args>
int foo(pack<T>, Args...)
{
    return sizeof(R);
}

template <class R, class T, class... Ts, class... Args>
int foo(pack<T, Ts...>, Args... args)
{
    return foo<T>(pack<Ts...>{}, args...);
}

int main() {
    // gcc: OK, clang: ambiguous
    foo<int>(pack<int>{});

    // gcc: ambiguous, clang: ambiguous
    foo<int>(pack<int>{}, 0);
}
```

Both gcc and clang accept both calls if the 2nd overload is changed to take a pack of at least 2 types instead of a pack of at least one type:

```
template <class R, class T, class T2, class... Ts, class... Args>
int foo(pack<T, T2, Ts...>, Args... args)
{
    return foo<T>(pack<T2, Ts...>{}, args...);
}
```

If the non-deduced template parameter is moved to a deduced template parameter, then:

```
template <class... > struct pack { };

template <class R, class T, class... Args>
int foo(pack<R>, pack<T>, Args...)
{
    return sizeof(R);
}

template <class R, class T, class... Ts, class... Args>
int foo(pack<R>, pack<T, Ts...>, Args... args)
{
    return foo(pack<T>{}, pack<Ts...>{}, args...);
}

int main() {
    // gcc ok with both, clang rejects both as ambiguous
    foo(pack<int>{}, pack<int>{});
    foo(pack<int>{}, pack<int>{}, 0);
}
```

I'd expect all the calls to be OK in every version of this. What is the expected outcome of the above code examples?

Comment: *I'd expect all the calls to be OK in every version of this.* Why? (I didn't.)

Comment: @Walter Because the first overload is more specialized than the second.

Answer (score 4):

I believe now that clang is correct to reject and gcc is incorrect to accept those forms that it does. Here's a simplified example:

```
template <class...> struct pack { };

// (1)
template <class T>
void foo(pack<T> ) { }

// (2)
template <class T, class... Ts>
void foo(pack<T, Ts...> ) { }

int main() {
    foo(pack<int>{});
}
```

Both overloads are valid, and deducing (2) from (1) succeeds straightforwardly. The only issue is can we deduce (1) from (2). I'd initially think no... But [temp.deduct.type]/9 states:

> If `P` has a form that contains `<T>` or `<i>`, then each argument P<sub>*i*</sub> of the respective template argument list of `P` is compared with the corresponding argument A<sub>*i*</sub> of the corresponding template argument list of `A`. [...] During partial ordering (14.8.2.4), if A<sub>*i*</sub> was originally a pack expansion:
>   — if `P` does not contain a template argument corresponding to A<sub>*i*</sub> then A<sub>*i*</sub> is ignored;

So when we synthesize types for `<T, Ts...>` (say `<U, Xs...>`), we deduce `T=U` and then there is no template argument corresponding to the pack expension `Xs...`, so we ignore it. All the non-ignored template parameters succeeded in template deduction, so we consider deducing (1) from (2) to be success.

Since deduction succeeds in both directions, neither function template is considered more specialized than the other, and the call should be ambiguous.

---

I have not yet submitted a bug report, waiting on some confirmation from the community.

Comment: I agree with your analysis, but... some more data points: EDG 4.11 in C++17 strict mode and MSVC 15 RC agree with GCC, choosing #1. The latest WP (N4618) received a couple of fixes related to this through [P0519](http://wg21.link/p0519), but they don't apply to this case. What *could* apply here would be a fix for [CWG1432](http://wg21.link/cwg1432), but they didn't address this one (oversight?). Depending on how the resolution for 1432 is worded, it could make your example non-ambiguous... or not. It may be that GCC, EDG and MSVC have ad-hoc implementations of such a resolution already.

Comment: Moreover, I think the latest fix makes a mess by rendering the last example in the DR (`int f(T*...)` vs `int f(const T&)`) non-ambiguous for a function call, but ambiguous for taking the address of a function template or deduction from a function declaration (because in the latter cases the whole function type is used for `P` and `A`, so the fix to  [temp.deduct.partial]/8 doesn't apply). I'm not sure if we can blame the poor compilers.

Comment: @bogdan Ugh... why do we keep adding these ultra-specific exceptions to situations rather than just making the rules themselves more sound?

Comment: @bogdan Submitted [gcc 78753](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78753) and started [a thread](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/zTTjuPlXJ2A). I also don't see why the `f(T*...)` vs `f(T const&)` case should be resolved - that seems like textbook neither is more specialized than the other.

Comment: I was hoping you'd start a thread :-). Let's see how this goes. When called with a pointer, I'd say intuitively you'd want `f(T*...)` to be picked (it's "specifically for pointers", right?), and the current resolution does that for a function call.

Comment: @bogdan I think it should be ambiguous - there's no way to state that one is a subset of the other. Also P0519 says to prefer the `const T&` version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130228/discussion-between-bogdan-and-barry).

Comment: please acknowledge (with a link) that the simplified version was taken from my answer -- I prefer not to edit your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Let's first simplify the problem and consider

```
template <class...> struct pack {};

template <class T>
void foo(pack<T>) {}

template <class T, class... Ts>
void foo(pack<T,Ts...>) {}

int main() {
  foo(pack<int>{});
}
```

which clang complains about and refused to compile, claiming that there is
ambiguity between `void foo(pack<T>)` [with `T=int`] and `void foo(pack<T,Ts...>)` [with `T=int`, `Ts=<>`]. Situations like this are resolved using [*partial ordering of overloaded function templates*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template), which essentially tries to find the most specialized overload.

In the case at hand, I think the following applies:

**In case of a tie, if one function template has a trailing parameter pack and the other does not, the one with the omitted parameter is considered to be more specialized than the one with the empty parameter pack.**

Thus it appears that the first should be preferred and clang was wrong.

Comment: There's no trailing parameter pack here.

Comment: @Barry Because it is deduced, right? I mean, it could be rewritten as `template <class... Ts, class T>` and still be valid. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Barry So what is?

Comment: @Walter `template <class T, class... Ts> void foo(T, Ts...)` <== that is a trailing parameter pack.

Comment: @Barry if can support this by more than your own authority, I'm happy accept it as answer to my related recent question about exactly this.

Comment: @Barry That would be a trailing _function_ parameter pack. `template <class T, class... Ts>` still contains a trailing _template_ parameter pack.